Ubuntu 24.04 External Microphone not working
I have an Acer Nitro AN515-44 that I've recently switched from windows to Ubuntu 24.04. Everything thus far has been great save for my Headset only works as an output. My system won't recognize the Headsets input. The headset uses a single 3.5mm Jack for both input and output.
I've tried using Pavucontrol and HDAJackRetask per the instructions in other similar questions on this site but have absolutely no idea what I'm looking at or working towards as I'm new to the Linux workflow,
I've been scouring this site for months for a fix, and it might just be me but I can't seem to figure this out. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Have you seen https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230016/headset-microphone-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/225017/how-do-i-change-which-audio-jacks-are-used-for-input-and-output?

I have tried all of the fixes in the first link and none of them made any positive changes. In the second link, the wget command from the first answer gives me a 404: Not Found Error.
